# Are Devil Fruits attracted to a specific user's will?

Tags: one-piece

I know that many Devil Fruit in the One Piece manga have been documented and catalogued in universe. For example Law's fruit abilities were already know before he ate the fruit  (and the very reason Flamingo was searching for that fruit in the first place).

At the same time I am wondering if the fruits are somehow attracted to a specific person since in many cases the fruit seems a good match for the user personality, even to the point it would be far less effective or useless in the hands of anyone else (Boa).

Some examples that come to mind:

- Luffy's Gum Gum Fruit or Nika Fruit, gives him flexibility/freedom which is Luffy's desire and will.
- DoFlamingo's String String Fruit, as he liked to puppet/control others.
- Boa Hancock's Love Love Fruit would probably be useless or at least far less effective for anyone else
- While Alvida undergo a radical change due to her fruit, it is strongly implied that she saw herself as beautiful even before (or at least she wanted to). It is possible that this is also true for Ivan (we don't know if the hormone based powers of their fruit was something they wished for before)
- Big Mom's Soul Soul Fruit, because she wanted the company of people/souls who'd also obey her. Considering how she found herself alone this also matches the theme of consuming other persons life.
- Whitebeard's Tremor Tremor Fruit, because of his will to be strong enough to protect his family.
- Marco Bird Bird Fruit (Phoenix), gives him both offensive and healing abilities considering his need to be the protector of his fellows being first commander and doctor.
- Blackbeard's Dark Dark Fruit because of his evil nature.
- Sakazuki's Magma Magma Fruit, for his extremely fiery behavior and will to burn away evil.
- Buggy's Chop Chop Fruit, he likely wished for Shanks to be a strong swordsman (as they were best friends at that time, probably now as well).

and a lot more.

While this can easily be justified as a plot device (having some user be a match for his power helps to write a better character) I was wondering if it could be an hint at something more.

I am therefore asking if there is any proof in the manga/show that some fruits are attracted to specific individuals based on some sort of compatibility or will power.

Comment: Notice: when helping you with the edit I took the liberty to remove you example about Blackbeard's crew sniper since in that case it looks like Blackbeard crew hunted down the fruit as oppose to finding it by chance

Comment: Yeah @SPArcheon, I had noticed, no worries